# Replace values of a pandas serie conditionally

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have to write a function that replaces all the values of a panda series which are smaller
than a by the mean value of the series. The series and the number a should be
parameters of the function.
For example, if the series is [10,11,12,3,4,5,7,9,15,20] , and a = 7, then the
resulting series should be [10.0,11.0,12.0,9.6,9.6,9.6,7.0,9.0,15.0,20.0]

I would like to know how to replace the values that are inferior to the mean by the mean value using series.replace function
The code i have written so far is :

```
import pandas as pd

def ex1(L,a):
    #Creating the Series 
    sr = pd.Series(L)
    result = sr.mean()
#replace values < the mean by the value of the mean
    sr.replace(to_replace=<9.6, value=result)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use loc indexing to update value directly.

```py
sr.loc[sr<7] = sr.mean()
```

so your final function will be

```py
def ex1(L,a):
    sr = pd.Series(L)
    #replace values < the mean by the value of the mean
    sr.loc[sr<a] = sr.mean()
    return sr
```

Also your function wasn't returning, I'm assuming you want to return.